# Angular thumbnail from local video file

Tags: angularjs, video, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am trying to generate thumbnails using angular-thumbnails (https://github.com/aztech-digital/angular-thumbnails) from local video files instead of video urls, this is what I have so far, it only works with some videos: https://plnkr.co/edit/j7LR7FU0itRmPmLJWgwT?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular-thumbnails']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('myFile', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
      $scope.myVideoData = reader.result;

      console.log('myVideoData', $scope.myVideoData);
    }, false);

    if (newVal) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(newVal); 
    }
  });
});

app.directive('fileModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      fileModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('change', function(e) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.fileModel = e.target.files[0];
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Found the problem, just needed a $scope.$apply when setting the value of myVideoData, updated the plunkr :)